# Repeat a row depending on Quantity

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a table of data formatted as:

```
+--------------+------+----------+
| Manufacturer | Item | Quantity |
+--------------+------+----------+
```

I need to re-arrange this so that each item has its own row so:

```
+--------------+------+----------+
| Manufacturer | Item | Quantity |
+--------------+------+----------+
| Coca Cola    | Coke |       4  |
+--------------+------+----------+
```

Becomes:

```
+--------------+------+
| Manufacturer | Item |
+--------------+------+
| Coca Cola    | Coke |
| Coca Cola    | Coke |
| Coca Cola    | Coke |
| Coca Cola    | Coke |
+--------------+------+
```

I've written this which works for a single line from the source table:

```
=split(transpose(split(rept(Join("|",A5:B5)&"$$", C5),"$$")),"|")
```

But I'm unsure how to expand this to an entire table. Doing this:

```
=arrayformula(split(transpose(split(rept(Join("|",A5:B)&"$$", C5:C),"$$")),"|"))
```

..just gives an error

> JOIN range must be a single row or a single column.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",", REPT(SPLIT(
 INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A1:A))&"♦"&
 INDIRECT("B1:B"&COUNTA(B1:B)), ",")&",", 
 INDIRECT("C1:C"&COUNTA(C1:C)))), ",")), "♦"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks. But when I try and adjust the ranges to `=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",", REPT(SPLIT(
 INDIRECT("A5:A"&COUNTA(A5:A))&"♦"&
 INDIRECT("B5:B"&COUNTA(B5:B)), ",")&",", 
 INDIRECT("C5:C"&COUNTA(C5:C)))), ",")), "♦"))` I get an error `Array arguments to REPT are of different size.`

Comment: Hmm. Works now. Must've been me! Thanks again